# SSRS expression value with/without equal/quotes?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In the SSRS expression, I am trying to configure the value for label Yes which should be Y. Which of the foll methods are appropriate to use?

1. ='Y'
2. ="Y"
3. =Y
4. 'Y'
5. "Y"
6. Y

[image: exprvalue]

Comment: Since the parameter is already listed as a string value, then number 6 should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need Expressiion for your Value of Parameter.
Simply give 1, 2 and so on and then you can use this value in your Reports for your calculations

[image]